# Jquery Ajax multiple input data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi i want learn ajax but i have same problem. So i click (a11) button  but my javascript alert 8, need to be 11.  my other question i post data with ajax but say "no" thanks.!

```
<form action="" method="post" onclick="return false;" >
    <input type="text"  name="idh" value="'.$id.'"></input>
    <button id="my_button" class="my_button" name="my_button" data-value="'.$id.'">'.$baslik.$id.'</button>
    </form>
```

and my script

```
$('.my_button').click(function() {  
        var idm = $(this).attr('data-value');
        var idh = $("input[name=idh]").val();
            idh = $.trim(idh);
        //alert (id);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: idm,
                success: function(cevapp){
                    alert (idh);
                }
            });
    });
```

my ajax.php

Comment: if ($_POST) {
 echo "yes";
 
}else{
 echo "no";
};